# Why does git not push files under some directories?

Tags: git

I host node.js app, which is based on Ghost, on Google Compute Engine, and use git to deploy my app via Cloud Registry.

However, when I downloaded some themes in my local repository, and pushed it over the Cloud Registry, for some reasons the git doesn't push all files under the theme directory.

The project structure is like the following:

```
core/
node_modules/
package.json
content/
...etc
```

And the theme is installed under the `content/themes/`, via `git clone`  from github (say. `content/themes/my-theme`).

Then, I added all files and commited it as usual, and pushed it to Cloud Registry.

```
git add content/themes/my-theme
git commit -a -m "add new theme"
git push google master
```

The Cloud Registry sees the directory `my-theme`, but it is empty and doesn't include any files at all.

Why does git not push any files under the directory?

For your information all the other directories have any files without any problems...

---

#### UPDATE

I tried to create a new, fake directory under the `content/themes/`, like `content/themes/temporary/` and put two fake files at it.

Then I git-commited but got the following output at the console.

```
[master 239696d] add new themes to test
 5 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 content/themes/temporary/README.md
 create mode 100644 content/themes/temporary/themes.txt
 create mode 160000 content/themes/caffeine-theme
```

The last one is another theme library from GitHub via `git clone`. So maybe does these set of libraries have problems in git-commiting?

Comment: Have you made sure there are no stray `.gitignore` files with definitions nested in the directory hierarchy of `my-theme`, including itself?

Comment: Git does not push *files* at all: Git pushes *commits*. This might seem kind of nit-picky (and might be!) but it's the key to diagnosing the problem. Assuming the other Git to which you are pushing gets and accepts the commits, the next step is to determine just what that Git *does* with the new commits, if anything.

Comment: @miqid Yeah I checked it.

Comment: [baseon on @torek comments] did these files were commited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `git clone` to download the themes from GitHub, Git is probably treating them as (incomplete) submodules. Try this:

```
git ls-tree HEAD -- content/themes/
```

I expect you will see that the theme directories are actually `commit` objects; links to a commit in another Git repository. Unfortunately, you haven't actually specified *which* other Git repository (using `git submodule`).

If that's the case, you have two paths forward:

1. Keep the cloned themes as submodules by adding entries to a root `.gitmodules` file in your repository, with entries that look like this:

   ```
   [submodule "content/themes/my-theme"]
       path = content/themes/my-theme
       url = https://github.com/owner/my-theme.git
   ```
2. Delete the `.git` folder in each theme directory, which should allow you to `git add` the themes' individual files.